# How to cast generic types that I know to be integers?

Tags: casting, rust, parametric-polymorphism

I want to check return codes of C APIs in a generic way and the result must be free from C types such as `libc::c_int`.  Are there any ways to write a function like

```
fn check<S: PartialOrd + std::num::Zero, T> (x: S) -> Option<T> {
    if std::num::zero::<S>() <= x { Some(x as T) }
    else { None }
}
```

when I'm sure that `S` and `T` are integral types for all usages of `check()`?  The compiler rejects my code complaining `` error: non-scalar cast: `S` as `T` ``

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is impossible to cast arbitrary type to arbitrary type, and that's exactly (almost) what you're trying to do. You need to be more specific in type constraints and conversion operations.

```
extern crate num;

use num::{Zero, NumCast};

fn check<S: PartialOrd + Zero + NumCast, T: NumCast>(x: S) -> Option<T> {
    if x >= S::zero() { Some(num::cast(x).unwrap()) }
    else { None }
}

fn main() {
    let x: i8 = 10;
    let y: Option<i32> = check(x);
    println!("{:?}", y);
    
    let x: i8 = -10;
    let y: Option<i32> = check(x);
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

Here I'm using a special trait, [`num::NumCast`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.NumCast.html) from `num` crate, which is implemented for all primitive types and provides a static method which converts to these types from anything which implements [`num::ToPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html). `num` crate also provides a function, [`num::cast::cast()`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/cast/fn.cast.html), which gives a simple interface to perform numeric casts.

Note that `cast(x)` returns `Option<T>`; it returns `None` if `x` can't be represented in the target type. I'm using `unwrap()` here because in your case, according to your description, inability to convert a value correctly is likely a programming error, so failing the task feels more appropriate. It is also possible to write `cast(x)` directly:

```
if x >= S::zero() { num::cast(x) }
...
```

In this case `check()` will return `None` not only when its argument is negative, but also if it is impossible to convert the argument to the result type.