# How to express integers other than zero and one in generic code using the num crate?

Tags: rust

The [num](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/index.html) crate in Rust provides a way of representing zeros and ones via [`T::zero()`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Zero.html#tymethod.zero) and [`T::one()`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.One.html#tymethod.one). Is there a way of representing other integers, such as two, three, etc.?

Consider the following (artificial) example:

```
extern crate num;

trait IsTwo {
    fn is_two(self) -> bool;
}

impl<T: num::Integer> IsTwo for T {
    fn is_two(self) -> bool {
        self == (T::one() + T::one())
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of representing `T::one() + T::one()` as `2`?

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I have decided to go with the answer of mine because it does not require creating any additional functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of representing arbitrary integers in generic code is to use the [`num::NumCast`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.NumCast.html) trait:

```
impl<T: num::Integer + num::NumCast> IsTwo for T {
    fn is_two(self) -> bool {
        self == T::from(2).unwrap()
    }
}
```

A related way is to use the [`num::FromPrimitive`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/cast/trait.FromPrimitive.html) trait:

```
impl<T: num::Integer + num::FromPrimitive> IsTwo for T {
    fn is_two(self) -> bool {
        self == T::from_i32(2).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Related questions and answers: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26042703/2580955), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41506857/2580955)].

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function:

```
fn two<T>() -> T 
    where T: num::Integer,
{
    let mut v = T::zero();
    for _ in 0..2 {
        v = v + T::one();
    }
    v
}
```

I've chosen this form because it's easily made into a macro, which can be reused for any set of values:

```
num_constant!(two, 2);
num_constant!(forty_two, 42);
```

I hear the concerns now... "but that's a loop and inefficient!". That's what optimizing compilers are for. Here's the LLVM IR for `two` when compiled in release mode:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline readnone uwtable
define internal fastcc i32 @_ZN10playground3two17hbef99995c3606e93E() unnamed_addr #3 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
bb3:
  br label %bb8

bb8:                                              ; preds = %bb3
  ret i32 2
}
```

That's right - it's been optimized to the value `2`. No loops.

Comment: Note that even in Debug mode, it's relatively trivial to build big integers with a relatively small number of calls: 2 = 1 + 1, 4 = 2 * 2 (aka (1 + 1) ^ 2), 8 = 2 * 2 * 2 (aka (1 + 1) ^ 3), ... so 2 is easy to get, and with 2 you finally have a base to work with.

Comment: @MatthieuM. a numbering system based on 2? Sounds interesting, but I can't imagine that we'd ever use something like that ;-) More seriously, the downside to that is that every value would have to be hand-expanded; the loop allows for one-stop shopping.

Comment: Oh certainly, with optimizations the loop is more elegant. The problem is that if you want `1 << 56` in Debug, it's gonna be complicated... As for the downside: I think you misunderstood how I was thinking to do it. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively simple to forge any number from 0 and 1:

- you need to create 2, which is hardly difficult
- you then proceed in converting your number to base 2, which takes O(log2(N)) operations

The algorithm is dead simple:

```
fn convert<T: Integer>(n: usize) -> T {
    let two = T::one() + T::one();

    let mut n = n;
    let mut acc = T::one();
    let mut result = T::zero();

    while n > 0 {
        if n % 2 != 0 {
            result += acc;
        }
        acc *= two;
        n /= 2;
    }

    result
}
```

And will be efficient both in Debug (O(log2(N)) iterations) and Release (the compiler optimizes it out completely).

For those who wish to see it in action, [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d8e52cfff0d94206562521c0b1a2b50a&version=stable&backtrace=0) we can see that `convert::<i32>(12345)` is optimized to `12345` as expected.

---

*As an exercise to the reader, implement a generic version of `convert` which takes any `Integer` parameter, there's not much operations required on `n` after all.*

Comment: Ah, you are right that I misunderstood. You still have the loop in there to do the conversion. Nice!

Comment: You can do `fn convert<T: Integer>(mut n: usize)` to save that line in the body.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I know, just prefer keeping my signatures short. The client doesn't care whether I mutate `n` or not.

Comment: Which is why the `mut` in `foo(mut bar)` doesn't show up in the API documentation - it's an implementation detail ;-)

Comment: @Shepmaster: Oh nice! You've got to love the attention to details in the docs :)